# duplicated items with mutation graph cool / graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphcool

I am using `graphcool` / `graphql` and want to add `Player` to a `Team`. My schema looks like the following:

```
type Team @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  name: String
  players: [Player!]! @relation(name: "TeamPlayers")
  fixtures: [Fixture!]! @relation(name: "TeamFixtures")
  results: [Result!]! @relation(name: "TeamResults")
}

type Player @model {
    id: ID! @isUnique
    name: String!
    gamesPlayed: Int!
    goalsScored: Int!
    yellowCards: Int!
    redCards: Int!
    photo: String!
    team: Team! @relation(name: "TeamPlayers")
}
```

I am making the following mutations:

```
mutation {
      createPlayer(
      name: "Peter Flanagan",
      gamesPlayed: 1,
      yellowCards: 0,
      redCards: 1,
      goalsScored: 4,
      photo: "http://cdn2-www.craveonline.com/assets/uploads/2017/02/bret1.png",
      team: {
        name: "Man United"
      }
    ) {
        id
      }
}
```

This works as expected, but if I make another mutation, like the one below, a second team, also called `Man United` with a new `id`.

```
mutation {
      createPlayer(
      name: "Eric Cantona",
      gamesPlayed: 1,
      yellowCards: 0,
      redCards: 1,
      goalsScored: 4,
      photo: "http://cdn2-www.craveonline.com/assets/uploads/2017/02/bret1.png",
      team: {
        name: "Man United"
      }
    ) {
        id
      }
}
```

Can anyone advise how I can avoid this issue and add both `Player`s to the same `Team`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way, you always create new `Team` with creating new `Player`. If you want to connect player to team. Create `team` first and get `teamId`. With `teamId` then you can create mutation what connects to team like this:

```
mutation {
  createPlayer(
  name: "Peter Flanagan",
  gamesPlayed: 1,
  yellowCards: 0,
  redCards: 1,
  goalsScored: 4,
  photo: "http://cdn2-www.craveonline.com/assets/uploads/2017/02/bret1.png",
  teamId: "TEAM_ID"
) {
    id
  }
}
```